# Ada package function identifier expected

Tags: function, package, ada

Learning Ada and trying to make a stack ADT and I'm using this webpage to figure it out.
http://www.functionx.com/ada/Lesson06.htm

eightqueens.adb

```
with Ada.Text_IO;
use Ada.Text_IO;
with Stack;
use Stack;

procedure EightQueens is
begin
    put_line ("awd");
end EightQueens;
```

stack.ads

```
package Stack is
    function awd () return Integer;
end Stack;
```

stack.adb

```
package body Stack is
    function awd () return integer is
    begin
        return 1;
    end awd;
end Stack;
```

Error is

```
stack.ads:2:19: identifier expected
```

I'm most certain I did everything correctly.

Comment: No, you didn't do everything correctly. Empty parenthesis are not allowed in Ada. Just define (and call) your function without them.

Comment: @egilhh: You should have posted that as an answer. If you decide to do so, post a comment here flagging me and I'll delete my answer.

Comment: That's not an ideal resource for Ada programming, since it stops at functions, and in any case it's a dreadful web site (the links appear to be automatically generated, and take you to quite irrelevant pages). There's a good set of links at the [Ada Information Clearinghouse](http://www.adaic.org/learn/materials/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ada doesn't use empty parentheses, either for defining or for calling functions or procedures.

And for future reference, the phrase "I'm most certain I did everything correctly." is a red flag indicating that you've almost certainly done *something* wrong.

Comment: Yea, only reason I said that was because that page didn't say empty parentheses weren't allowed.

Comment: @TreeTree: Nor, I presume, did it say they were required or permitted. Just sayin'.

Answer (score 3):

Just to elaborate, there are some syntactic decisions that Ada made that IMHO are superior to what you may be used to from C-syntax languages.

1. Functions with no parameters don't use empty parenthesis in their calls. This allows you to change a contant to a function call without having to recode any of the clients.
2. Arrays use parentheses like function calls do, rather than some unique syntax. This allows you to change an array constant to a function call without having to recode any of the clients.

To look at it another way, a constant is just a simplified version of a parameterless function, for when you can get away with always returning the same value. Likewise, a constant array is a simplified version of a parametered function call, for when you can get away with always returning the same value. If you later discover you need a more complex implementation, that's not the client's concern, and should not affect their code.

Comment: I know that was the intent, but I've never been convinced that it was a good idea. Function calls, constants, and arrays are different things, and IMHO they should look different. I don't see much benefit in making them look alike. And I don't recall ever taking advantage of the ability to change a constant or an array reference to a function call, or vice versa. If you see a bare identifier in an expression, you can't tell whether it might have side effects without tracking down its definition.

Comment: @KeithThompson - Really? I've done that a lot. Different people have different toolboxes, I guess. I'll admit it does have the implication you mention WRT side effects. If you find that to be a huge drawback, I can see your point. I haven't really ever felt that way about it though. (If unexpected opportunities for side-effects bug you, you must really loathe C++. I does the same thing with default constructors, implict conversion constructors, array operator overloading, etc).

Comment: @KeithThompson - I've got an example for you, as a way I could go with my OpenGL binding I could have the object-enumerations be the mandatory minimums, then replace them with the function-call to get the actual number as a function expression. {I've actually decided on using parameters to a generic package to do so.}